# Provide get commands to SFTP from a script file but keep interactive password login

Tags: openssh, sftp

I have an FTP server that allows only SFTP connection – and only via password.

I have a list of files on the server - hundreds and thousands of files in many directories. And the directories contain a loooot of files we don't need. So, I have to fetch files on-by-one, controlled by the list.

The way I hoped to use is to create a script with a list of

```
get -p source_file dest.dir
```

commands – and feed it to the `sftp` command. But when I connect to the server in interactive mode, I cannot make `sftp` to consume the list.

The batch mode of `sftp` demands the remote machine to provide non-password identification.

What is the way to get files by list?

Comment: You should look into this other client which has a lot of features: [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/). It exists at least for Linux FreeBSD and Solaris, and I'm sure there are many other ports. Of course it supports the SFTP protocol.

Comment: Do you have `expect` available at the client side?

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting client! Sure it must be among the tools. Yet, I have to work on the remote machine and there's little or no chance to push the installation of lftp on the machine.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, no.

Comment: @A.B, meanwhile I'm considering the use of 2 streams: get file from the server on my local machine and instantly put it to the client machine - all it in the lftp script. Well, it doubles the traffic, but it resolves the problem. If I manage to run 2 scripts and to sync them - well, it would be quite a sensible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide the commands to `sftp` without the batch mode using an input redirection:

```
sftp username@example.com < commands.txt
```

This way you can still use an interactive password authentication.

```
$ sftp username@example.com < commands.txt
username@example.com's password:
Connected to username@example.com.
sftp> get -p source_file dest
Fetching /path/source_file to dest
/path/source_file                                        100% 9474   975.4KB/s   00:00
sftp>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! It works. Actually, it resolves my question completely, since sftp is available on the Linux client machine I have to work with.